# How to compile/build other JS files into main.js on Electron/Vue

Tags: webpack, vue.js, electron

I'm using `electron-vue` boilerplate and I'm trying to add custom modules/services to be compiled/builded into `dist/electron/main.js`. I couldn't find how to do that. I already tried to edit the file `webpack.web.config.js` and add a new file in the rule `/\.js$/`

`{
  test: /\.js$/,
  use: 'babel-loader',
  include: [ path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/renderer'), path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/services') ],
  exclude: /node_modules/
}`

It didn't work.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by importing the service in my code:

`import Debug from 'services/debug'`

Now it's compiled/builded all together.